# Do I need all the Dijinni to complete the game?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

The dijnni seem pretty important when it comes to fighting battles. I am trying to collect them all, but I am afraid I have missed at least one already, in an area that I cannot go back to.

If I have already missed one of the Dijinni, is it going to severely impact my ability to finish the game? Or am I okay to miss some of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible to finish the game without getting all the Djinni.  When I went though the game, I thought I was being quite thorough about getting into all the nooks and crannies to find all of them.  Imagine my surprise, by the end of the game, I was missing about a half-dozen or so.  It didn't impact my ability at all to take out the end boss.

Obviously, you don't get all the stat increases or classes, but that's more for completeness's sake than any requirement for the end boss.

Plus, it would be pretty bad game design to require every Djinni to beat the game, and then go and ensure that some of them are missable, thereby making sure you can't finish the game.

Comment: I figured it wouldn't require having all of them, but I was hoping that it wouldn't make it too hard, so I was delighted to see your answer. :)